# how to solve error "psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "base_registry_signaling" already exists - - " in odoo14?

Tags: odoo

I got this error after restored the database. I granted all privileges to the database using certain psql commands. Now, I messed up with an error "psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "base_registry_signaling" already exists - - ".

Could anyone please help me to solve this!

Comment: Hi, try './odoo-bin -u all' command

Comment: It still shows an error

Comment: Your backup coming from an other Odoo V14 instance ?

Comment: I don't know why this problem occurred.

Answer (score 2):

This error means Odoo is trying to create a new database, but it can't because the database already exists. Odoo probably doesn't have access rights to your database.

The owner of database must be the same as the `db_user` that you added in the Odoo configuration file.

Comment: Yes i had done as you said. But still there's an error.

Answer (score 2):

Please check for the **database owner** and **owner of tables** in the database.

command to change the owner of the database:-

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName OWNER TO UserName;
```

use this command to change table owner:-

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY old_role [, ...] TO new_role
```